# Is it possible with Audit.EntityFramework to ignore inserts on certain entities?

Tags: audit.net

I want to use Audit.EntityFramework with EntityFramework Core but ignore inserts in audit logs only for some entities. I cannot find any info about that on the github documentation for Audit.EntityFramework. Maybe someone faced same problem and could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [readme document](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md) for Audit.EntityFramework

You can choose between and Opt-In or an Opt-Out mechanism. You can [ignore/include entities](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md#includeignore-entities-tables) by decorating the entity models or [by configuration](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md#fluent-api) on your startup.

Sample extract from the documentation:

```
Audit.EntityFramework.Configuration.Setup()
    .ForContext<MyContext>(config => config
        .IncludeEntityObjects()
        .AuditEventType("{context}:{database}"))
    .UseOptOut()
        .IgnoreAny(t => t.Name.EndsWith("History"));
```